# JavaScript return and php problem (true,false)

Tags: php, jquery

now i made JavaScript code (jquery code) and when i click ok it return true if i want true and false if i want false

now the problem is php not consider true as `php keyword true` its just consider it a word like any other word and i must make it like this

```
if($post == 'true')
```

and i want make it like this

```
if($post) // retuen true if $post true
```

how i can do that
and i use jquery function `is()` to send true or false to php

Comment: please provide your jquery code.

Comment: its not important my dear its general problem

Comment: send `0` for `false` and `1` for `true`

Comment: i mean how to convert java script true to php true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Raveren said, you can't send integer, or boolean to PHP. All sent data is string, always. If you still want to use *if ($post)* and not *if ($post == 'true')* then use *switch*

```
switch($post)
{
    case "true":
        $post = true;
        break;
    case "false":
        $post = false;
        break;
}

if ($post) {
    ...
}
```

no other way to do it

Answer (score 6):

Javascript can only send values to serverside PHP via POST or GET. The data is always of type string - even numbers, although PHP being a typeless language, the difference is hardly noticeable. You should return 0 or 1 and typecast it to bool if you really need it. One way to force a value to bool is `boolVariable = !! variable;`

Comment: An alternative - you could return it as JSON using json_encode, I suppose, but that's a bit overkill.